# Android / Eclipse: why do I have to unplug/replug my device each time before launching my app?

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, usb, device

I have since few days an issue I never had before. When I want to run my app, the window to choose a device appears but its is empty. I have to unplug and replug my phone at each run in order to get my device in the list. I am becoming crazy !!!

Do you know how to solve this issue ?

I am on a MAc computer and my phone is a Samsung S2.

Comment: Have you tried a reboot?

Comment: You will have more luck by asking this question @ http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: How did you solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It finally appeared that I had a hardware problem with the micro-usb connection on my Samsung S2 (unstable connection due to a damaged connection). I brought my device t Samsung to be repaired...and it fixed it !

I heard that some people fixed this problem by updating all the components in Eclipse:

1) "Help" menu => check for updates => update all modules
2) Go to the "Android SDK Manager" (icon with the Android symbol in the Eclipse tool bar) and update all the modules which are not updated

But I repeat, for me, it was an hardware problem: usb connection on Samsung S2 are not very reliable on the 'long' term (less than 1 year of dev for me...).